# Walk (GET_NEXT) entire agent MIB space?

Tags: snmp

What is the best practice for discovering the capabilities of an SNMP agent?

My expectation is that I can simply walk the entire agent by starting with GET_NEXT on mib-2.system (e.g. `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public host`) however that doesn't seem to work with most agents, it only gets you the system MIB itself, it doesn't continue on to the other MIBs.

My Cisco router does approximately what I would expect, it walks through the system MIB including the sysORTable which has many, many entries.  When that is finished it starts in with the IF-MIB and presumably walks all of the available MIBs (I say "presumably" because my router started slowing down and then ground to a halt and had to be rebooted!).

The intention in the SNMP framework seems to be that an agent would advertise it's capabilities in the sysORTable by an OID for an AGENT-CAPABILITIES macro in sysORID.  This seems quite sensible as it communicates not just the MIBs available but also how they are implemented.  However I see that Cisco don't follow RFC2580 completely, in sysORID they place the OID of a MIB containing AGENT-CAPABILITIES macros for various product models.  Then in sysDesc they include text from the MIB identifying the name of the AGENT-CAPABILITIES macro for the specific product and other identifying information (e.g. date).  Other agents just use OIDs of the implemented MIBs in sysORID.

I'm building my own agent.  I've been thinking about how to get my tools to do what I want but I wonder if what I want is very commonly implemented?  I wonder if it's even wise as if the MIBs include large tables it might be impractical (e.g. my router crashing above).  For a simple agent however it seems like the most practical thing to do would be to just walk all the available MIBs.

Answer (score 0):

The default config file for `snmpd` has a `systemonly` view assigned to the `public` community which it enforces for requests from any non-localhost IP address. It limits you to seeing only OIDs under the `1.3.6.1.2.1.1` and `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1` trees.

To remove this restriction, look in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` for a line that looks like this

```
rocommunity public  default   -V systemonly
```

Delete the `-V systemonly` bit, and then restart `snmpd` with `sudo systemctl stop snmpd`.

Answer (score -2):

What you're wanting to do is called an SNMP walk and ,unless you like reinventing wheels or have some specific need, has been done plenty of times [here is a free one](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Snmpwalk)